# How can i get these Javascript functions to increment correctly without combining with my original variable?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I'm currently doing a Javascript challenge on Scrimba that requires you to recreate a Basketball scoreboard. I've gotten the design down but i'm having trouble with increment buttons to add either 1,2, or 3 points to either teams score. Each team's scoreboard has 3 buttons underneath that can add 1,2, or 3 points. Originally i was just going to write 6 functions, 3 for each team that would function based on which increment button you select for which team. I figured i could probably just write the three separate increment functions and find a way to pass in an argument to direct which team was getting the points. This worked except that the functions all target a 'points' variable so they end up incrementing off of each other when you add points to the opposite team.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="column">
                <h3 class="title">HOME</h3>
                <h2 class="score" id="home-score">0</h2>
                <div>
                    <button class="increment-btn" onclick="add1Point('home-score')">+1</button>
                    <button class="increment-btn" onclick="add2Points('home-score')">+2</button>
                    <button class="increment-btn" onclick="add3Points('home-score')">+3</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <h3 class="title">GUEST</h3>
                <h2 class="score" id="guest-score">0</h2>
                <div>
                    <button class="increment-btn" onclick="add1Point('guest-score')">+1</button>
                    <button class="increment-btn" onclick="add2Points('guest-score')">+2</button>
                    <button class="increment-btn" onclick="add3Points('guest-score')">+3</button>
                </div>
```

And here is the JS

```
let points = 0

function add1Point(idValue){
    let teamId = document.getElementById(idValue)
    points += 1
    teamId.textContent = points
}
function add2Points(idValue){
    let teamId = document.getElementById(idValue)
    points += 2
    teamId.textContent = points
}
function add3Points(idValue){
    let teamId = document.getElementById(idValue)
    points += 3
    teamId.textContent = points
}
```

I know i need to find a way to have two separate point variables for each team but I'm not sure how i can point the individual functions to a specific variable base on which teams button is selected. Not without creating a whole new function specifically for that variable. If possible i would like a solution with the most basic vanilla JS possible, I know there are more complex ways to solve this but im only so far with my learning. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a single `points` value. You need a `points` value per team, and you have team IDs--sounds like an object/map w/ ID keys and points values.

Comment: *(Unrelated, but three functions doesn't seem super-helpful either.)*

Comment: In it's basic form, is it possible to check the value of idValue and then apply the score to the correct points var.  i.e. if (teamId == 1) { points++; } else { points2++; }_.  Of course, that would for this to work, teamId would need to be fixed each time to be the same values, but you didn't disclose this in your question so I'm not sure

Comment: You don't even need a variable, you can just do this: `teamId.textContent = parseInt(teamId.textContent) + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you'd probably need 2 individual variables to hold the value for each team, here's an example for add 1 point

```
let guest = 0;
let home = 0;

function add1Point(idValue){
    let teamId = document.getElementById(idValue)
    if (idValue === 'guest-score') { //Assume your element has name to tell them apart
         guest += 1;
         teamId.textContent = guest;
    } else {
         home += 1;
         teamId.textContent = home;
    }
}
```

In the other hand, you should make your method reusable and flexible a little like this

```
function addPoints(idValue, point)  {
    let teamId = document.getElementById(idValue)
    if (idValue === 'guest-score') { //Assume your element has name to tell them apart
        guest += point;
        teamId.textContent = guest;
    } else {
        home += point;
        teamId.textContent = home;
    }
}
```

then your code will look cleaner

```
<button class="increment-btn" onclick="addPoints('guest-score', 1)">+1</button>
<button class="increment-btn" onclick="addPoints('guest-score', 2)">+2</button>
<button class="increment-btn" onclick="addPoints('guest-score', 3)">+3</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the straight foward response! I'm still pretty new to JS but i understand all the concepts you used. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

use closures

```js
    function score(points = 0) {
      return function(value) {
        points += value;
        return points;
      }
    }

    const $homeScore = document.getElementById("home-score");

    const $guestScore = document.getElementById("guest-score");

    const homeScore = score();

    const guestScore = score();

    const $homeButtons = document.querySelectorAll("#home-buttons button");

    const $guestButtons = document.querySelectorAll("#guest-buttons button");

    for(let i = 0; i < $homeButtons.length; i++) {
      $homeButtons[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
        $homeScore.innerText = homeScore(i + 1);
      });
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < $guestButtons.length; i++) {
      $guestButtons[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
        $guestScore.innerText = guestScore(i + 1);
      });
    }
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: Courier, Courier New, monospace;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}

.container .column .score {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <h3 class="title">HOME</h3>
    <h2 class="score" id="home-score">0</h2>
    <div id="home-buttons">
        <button class="increment-btn">+1</button>
        <button class="increment-btn">+2</button>
        <button class="increment-btn">+3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h3 class="title">GUEST</h3>
    <h2 class="score" id="guest-score">0</h2>
    <div id="guest-buttons">
        <button class="increment-btn">+1</button>
        <button class="increment-btn">+2</button>
        <button class="increment-btn">+3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it to one function only:

```js
var homeScore = 0;
var guestScore = 0;
var homeScoreEl = document.getElementById('home-score');
var guestScoreEl = document.getElementById('guest-score');

function addPoints(isHome, points = 1) {
  window[isHome ? 'homeScore' : 'guestScore'] += points
  window[isHome ? 'homeScoreEl' : 'guestScoreEl'].textContent = window[isHome ? 'homeScore' : 'guestScore']
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: Courier, Courier New, monospace;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}

.container .column .score {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="column">
                <h3 class="title">HOME</h3>
                <h2 class="score" id="home-score">0</h2>
                <div>
                    <button class="increment-btn" onclick="addPoints(true)">+1</button>
                    <button class="increment-btn" onclick="addPoints(true, 2)">+2</button>
                    <button class="increment-btn" onclick="addPoints(true, 3)">+3</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <h3 class="title">GUEST</h3>
                <h2 class="score" id="guest-score">0</h2>
                <div>
                    <button class="increment-btn" onclick="addPoints(false)">+1</button>
                    <button class="increment-btn" onclick="addPoints(false, 2)">+2</button>
                    <button class="increment-btn" onclick="addPoints(false, 3)">+3</button>
                </div>
```